# Aws::CognitoIdentity::Errors::NotAuthorizedException Exception: Invalid login token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working with a `Rails application`, and i am using `amazon cognito` for `single sign on`, i have created an identity provider that is linked to my user pool, now i am trying to get `identity_id` from my cognito identity using the code as said in [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentity/Types/GetIdInput.html#logins-instance_method)

```
cognitoidentity = Aws::CognitoIdentity::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1',)

cognitoidentity.get_id({identity_pool_id: "us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", logins: { "www.amazon.com" => <Access token got from #admin_initiate_auth method>}})
```

I am getting this error:

> Aws::CognitoIdentity::Errors::NotAuthorizedException Exception:
>   Invalid login token

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using User Pools then the idp identifier in your Logins map should not be "www.amazon.com". The logins map should look like this:

`Logins: {

'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': <IdToken>

}`

This page doesn't provide a Ruby example, but you should refer to it to get the idea:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html